# Backbone.js with class structure instead of prototypes is not a backwards step?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm extremely new in Backbone.js, so, is backbone.js essentially bringing class structure to javascript? If so, isn’t that a backwards step? Javascripts prototypes are more powerful according to Douglas Crockford.

Answer (score 5):

Backbone uses prototypes. There are no "class structures" in JavaScript, in spite of how Backbone looks.

For example:

```
Backbone.Model.prototype.sayFoo = function(){
  alert("foo");
};

MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({});

m = new MyModel();
m.sayFoo(); // => "foo" alert box
```

I use prototypes in Backbone all the time, and the creator of Backbone (Jeremy Ashkenas) also uses them in Backbone a lot.

What you are seeing as a "class structure" is an object literal used to define the methods on the object.

This:

```
Backbone.Model.extend({
  initialize: function(){
  }
});
```

is the exact same code as this:

```
var myDef = {
  initialize: function(){
  }
};

Backbone.Model.extend(myDef);
```

The only difference is that in the second version, I declared the object definition as a variable instead of just passing it directly into the Model extend method.

Comment: But he uses the word "class" in the documentation.

Comment: Documentation doesn't matter that much. He could have used the word "foo" instead, and it wouldn't change how the code works. The use of "class" is likely there to help people understand what's going on without getting into all the detail of prototypal inheritance. That, and Jeremy created CoffeeScript, which does have a "class" keyword, so it may be bleed over from that.